# How do I open this spiky chest?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth

I found a spiky chest. I'm assuming it's going to hurt me when I touch it. Is there any way I can open it without getting damaged?

[image: Spiky chest]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Rebirth wikia](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Chest#Spike_Chests):

> **Spike Chests** are purple colored chests with spikes protruding from it that will deal damage to Isaac upon opening it.

I think that the only way to open that kind of chest without getting damaged is having [*Holy Mantle*](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Holy_Mantle), [*Isaac's Heart*](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Isaac%27s_Heart) or another item that protect Isaac from direct damage.

Answer (score 2):

Long and short: No. This chest will always deal you damage - it's kinda a requirement to open the chest. Touching it from any side (to open the chest) will cause damage, not just from the front.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options:

- put a bomb over the rock in the top-right of the chest, the explosion will move the rock into the gap to the right of the chest
- put a bomb to the right of that rock, the explosion will move it into the gap at the top of the chest
- put a bomb below the rock in the bottom-left of the chest, the explosion will move the rock into the gap to the left of the chest
- put a bomb to the left of that rock, the explosion will move it into the gap at the bottom of the chest.

Upon touching the chest, you will be dealt damage (no way around it) and the chest will open.

Comment: I knew about the bombs blowing up rocks, accessing the chest is easy. I just wanted to open it without getting a spike in my hands.